# Another Proof for Center of Non-Abelian Group of Order $pq$ is $\{e\}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, alternative-proof

I want to show that

> If $G$ non-abelian group of order $pq$ with $p,q$ primes then $Z(G)=\{e\}$.

It's immediate that if $Z(G) \neq \{e\}$ then $|Z(G)|=p$ or $|Z(G)|=q$ and using that any group of prime order is cyclic then $G / Z(G)$ is cyclic, which implies that $G$ is abelian and therefore we have a contradiction.

I wanted to know if it's possible to prove it without using the theorem that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian because my professor hasn't mentioned it before. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to prove the contrapositive—if $Z(G)\ne\{e\}$ then $G$ is abelian. Hint: if $x\in Z(g)\ne\{e\}$, what are the possible orders of $g$? Show that each possibility leads to an abelian group.

Comment: The duplicate has an answer not using that if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian.

Comment: If you know the Class Equation, I've posted an answer in the duplicate which doesn't use the quotient argument.